# how to save the state of the activity when user pressed select?

Tags: android

i have created dynamic table-layout. in that layout in each row have four buttons.one  button is use to navigate from one activity to another. my problem is when i switch from 1st activity to second activity  by pressing button and i come back from 2nd activity to 1st activity clicked button loose its state.

Ex. 1) in 1st Activity i click button 1 and check the check box and go to 2nd activity after doing some operation  i come back to 1st activity and i see the button1  and check box are unclicked and unchecked.

so how to maintain states of buttons

Answer (score 1):

obviously it would be happen because i have to maintain the check box state when its come on the on resume() ..u can take a shared preferance to mantain the check box state .

Answer (score 0):

Use variables and store the values in the variable when u clicked the button. Store that variable values in the Bundle object using the  bundle.putExtras...() method. send this bundle object to the other activity using Intent.putExtra...s();. In the same manner ,if u need the those values then resend that bundle object and get that bundle object using Intent.getExtras....();. And finally restore the values from the bundle object.

This information may solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for answer but if u have some code for it please send me.thanks